# RLC circuit split into two circuits RC & RL after the switch is closed

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit, thevenin

I have the following circuit (old exam question) that asked to find \$i_{C}(t) \geq 0 ,i_{L}(t) \geq 0 \$[image]

For \$t <0 \$ the switch was open. Therefore the inductor behaves as a short circuit and the capacitor as an open circuit. The given circuit for  \$t <0 \$ becomes :

[image]

Now all I want is to find the Thevenin equivalent of this reduced circuit.The \$i_{C}(t) =i_{Norton} \$ and the \$i_{L}(t) = 0 \$. Am I correct for far ?

For \$V_{th}\$ I have the node equation :

\$\frac{V_{0}-30}{6} +\frac{V_{0}}{12}+ \frac{V_{0}}{6}=0\$
Which gives : \$V_{0}=12=V_{th}\$

So \$i_{L}(t=0^{-}) = \frac{V_{0}}{6}=\frac{12}{6}=2\$

For the \$R_{th} = ((6||12) || 6 )+2 = 4.4\$

Therefore \$i_{Nort} = \frac{12}{4.4} = \approx 2.7 =i_{C}(t =0^{-})\$

For \$t \geq 0 \$ the switch closes.So I have now two independent circuits.One RL on the left and one RC on the right, because when the switch closes creates a short circuit (no current is flowing through it.The correct is that there is no voltage across a short circuit but here  \$i_{L}(t) = 0 \$ from \$t<0\$).

The circuit on the left will be :

[image]

The inductor is removed , and I calculate again the thevenin equivalent.

As for the right circuit will be :

[image]

I was some help in order to understand if I have correctly understood was is going on or if I am completely out. Any help ?

Comment: Well, the whole purpose of \$t<0\$ is to work out the initial conditions for \$I_L\$ and \$V_C\$. Do you have quantitative values for these, yet? What have you worked out as \$I_L\left(t=0^-\right)\$ and \$V_C\left(t=0^-\right)\$?

Comment: @periblepsis my calculations give \$i_{L}(t=0^{-})=2\$ and the \$Vth=V_{c}(t=0^{-})=12\$

Comment: Okay. That should be included in your question so that others know you've got that part worked out. But agreed, so far. The rest that follows? Not so much.

Comment: At and after \$t=0^+\$ don't you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMrrs.png)? I mean, isn't the \$6\:\Omega\$ resistor now completely bypassed?

Comment: @periblepsis yes you are correct.And the reason is that the 6 ohm resistor is parallel to a short circuit.But the capacitor as well is parallel to the short circuit.?

Comment: No. Because of the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor in series with it. Not so?

Comment: @periblepsis yes but also the 6 ohm resistor is parallel to the short circuit.So are saying that will be a 8 ohm resistor ?

Comment: No. The switch bypasses and ***only*** bypasses the \$6\:\Omega\$ resistor. How is it that you imagine either (1) that a bypassed \$6\:\Omega\$ resistor could add to a \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor or (2) that the switch bypasses the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor? The switch does neither of these. And you ***need*** to be able to see this fact. If you cannot, then you are not going to process the schematic well. A wire in parallel to a resistor bypasses the resistor. You can erase *that* resistor. But you don't get to erase anything else.

Comment: @periblepsis ok now I got you

Comment: A short circuit has zero *voltage*, not zero current.